# How did the Nexus exactly work?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek Generations, the only way to get into the Nexus was to basically collide with it as it traveled through space.

My understanding is, once inside the Nexus, they can make a decision to leave it at any time, and show up at any place.

How exactly did the Nexus have these powers to transport someone to a place far away from where the Nexus is itself?

Maybe the bigger question is, how exactly did the Nexus work?

Comment: I reference TVTropes: [New Powers as the Plot Demands](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NewPowersAsThePlotDemands)

Comment: What always bugged me about the nexus, is kirk says "I was on the 
                             Enterprise-B... in the deflector 
                             control room..." "                             The bulkhead in front of me 
                             Disappeared... then I was out 
                             there chopping wood." Its been like 75 years since? so where had kirk been since then... P.s BBK ; )

Comment: @Jared - Guinan states explictly that the Nexus exists outside time.

Comment: @Jared Guinan literally says "for him, he just got here"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Guinan explained to Picard, time has no meaning inside the Nexus. That is why when Picard went to visit Kirk, Kirk had only just arrived (not years later). This also explains why a person could exit to any *time* from the Nexus.
As for the any where component, I can only imagine that over the course of the life of the galaxy the nexus has traveled across every spot in the galaxy. A bit far fetched, perhaps, but it is the only explaination I have for that.

Comment: Regarding your explanation for "anywhere":  This would require that the person leaving exits the Nexus at a time when the Nexus is at their destination.  While this may feel like a time of their choosing from within the Nexus, it could be years or even millenia later when they're outside.

Answer (score 2):

Nexus can be assumed as an array of parallel dimensions. Each parallel dimension allows only one real person to exist and is modified according to person's dreams. It also allows that person to leave Nexus at anytime & go back to original dimension at any point of time & space.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing is very strange.  Inside the Nexus time has no meaning, and if one gets inside it one can effectively live forever, while being perfectly content.  On the other hand, on the outside the Nexus is affected by gravity, since destroying a star has altered its course through space.